# Why partition is not showing, sudo fdisk - l

Tags: installation, partitioning, gparted

I'm really new to Ubuntu and pretty scared with things right now. There were two partitions in the system partition 1 and partition 2 with ext4 format. Since I couldn't access them (I mean I couldn't create a folder or document or anything) I deleted these partitions and created new ones D and E with ntfs format. Now when I give

```
sufo fdisk-l
```

What I get is this

```
sujatha@sujatha-cellapp:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for sujatha: 

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
sujatha@sujatha-cellapp:~$
```

But I had GParted create two partions D and E and I could see them then why it's not shown above..??

Also while starting system I could see a message showing like this

```
The disk drive for /partition 1 is not ready yet or not found
Continue to wait, or Press S to akip mounting or f for manual recovery
```

My GParted after partition looks like this after partition

```
Partition     File System     Mount Point    Label   Size    Used    Unused   Flags

/dev/sda1          ext4          /                 47.68GiB   43.57GiB  4.11GiB
/dev/sda2          linux-swap                      977.00MiB   --         --
/dev/sda4          ntfs                        D   208.08GiB  70.98MiB  208.02GiB msftdata
/dev/sda5          ntfs                        E   208.09GiB  70.98MiB  208.08GiB msftdata
/dev/sda3          fat32      /boot/efi            976.00MiB  5.22MiB   970.78MiB  boot
unallocated                                        1.02MiB     --         --
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. When you open Gparted a second time. Do you see the partitions?

Comment: @MadMike thanks. Yeah i could see the D and E partitions there

Comment: But, can you see them *now*?

Comment: @MadMike yes I can see them I cant post images otherwise i will have put it up over here

Comment: @MadMike i have added the gparted partition table to my post

Comment: Apparently your have installed a GPT on you hard-disk and fdisk can't deal it. I'm not sure what your question is now.

Comment: @MadMike kk then why on start up it keeps asking adout older partition

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12897/discussion-between-madmike-and-suja)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is in the first output that `fdisk` produced:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

Your disk uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which the version of `fdisk` you're using doesn't support. You must use GParted, `parted`, `gdisk`, or some other GPT-aware tool to partition the disk, not `fdisk`. (The latest versions of `fdisk` do support GPT, but they don't yet ship with Ubuntu.)